# No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer_v1' in python code with tensor flow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

hi i'm doing this code in google colab and i have this error **No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer_v1' in python code with tensor flow keras**

i did use tensorflow.keras instead of keras since i use tensorflow v=2.1.0
and keras v=2.3.0-tf

```
i tried both tensorflow  v=2.1.0 and v=2.2.0-rc2
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, SpatialDropout1D
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

MAX_NB_WORDS=50000
EMBEDDING_DIM=100

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=train.shape[1]))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(13, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

epochs = 5
batch_size = 64
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, min_delta=0.0001)])

accr = model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)
print('Test set\n  Loss: {:0.3f}\n  Accuracy: {:0.3f}'.format(accr[0],accr[1]))
```

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces your problem. Since you're attempting to replace the system TensorFlow and keras versions, your initialization process will be important to diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Always share the entire Traceback while asking the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar error while working with gaborNet-CNN. I tired following and it worked in my case.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras import activations, initializers, regularizers, constraints, metrics
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import (Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Reshape, Layer,
                          BatchNormalization, LocallyConnected2D,
                          ZeroPadding2D, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Conv2DTranspose,
                          GaussianNoise, UpSampling2D, Input)
from keras.utils import conv_utils, multi_gpu_model
from keras.layers import Lambda
from keras.engine import Layer, InputSpec
from keras.legacy import interfaces
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case, I just reinstall keras and it works